# How can I read .dat file in node.js and convert to human-readable text/json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `.dat` file that contains information that is not clear to read it.

So, I was trying to read that file and convert it to human-readable text/json.

I implemented this code but don't know how to convert readable text/json file.

```
 fs.readFile('./2.dat', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(data)
  })
```

This is the file [2.dat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xaTDsJpnOGkMHp8P_EAVuCjnyT55zaTC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `dat` is a very generic name for files containing some kind of data. You need to find (or write) a parser for whatever data format it actually contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file looks like some kinf of CSV with `|` as a delimiter. YOu need to use some package to parse CSV like `csv-parse` to get lines as JS-objects.